# How to use tensorflow ctc beam search properly?

Tags: python, tensorflow, beam-search, ctc

I want to perform CTC Beam Search on (the output of an ASR model that gives) matrices of phoneme probability values.
Tensorflow has a CTC Beam Search [implementation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/ctc_beam_search_decoder) but it's poorly documented and I fail to make a working example. I want to write a code to use it as a benchmark.

Here is my code so far:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def decode_ctcBeam(matrix, classes):
      matrix = np.reshape(matrix, (matrix.shape[0], 1,matrix.shape[1]))
      aa_ctc_blank_aa_logits = tf.constant(matrix)
      sequence_length = tf.constant(np.array([len(matrix)], dtype=np.int32))

      (decoded_list,), log_probabilities = tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder(inputs=aa_ctc_blank_aa_logits,
                                          sequence_length=sequence_length,
                                          merge_repeated=True,
                                          beam_width=25)

      out = list(tf.Session().run(tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(decoded_list)[0]))    
      print(out)

      return out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    classes = ['AA', 'B', 'CH']
    mat = np.array([[0.4, 0, 0.6, 0.2], [0.4, 0, 0.6, 0.2]], dtype=np.float32)

    actual = decode_ctcBeam (mat, classes)
```

I'm having issues with understanding the code:

- in the example **mat** is shaped (2, 4), but the tensorflow module needs a (2, 1, 4) shape, so I reshape **mat** with 
  `matrix = np.reshape(matrix, (matrix.shape[0], 1,matrix.shape[1]))`
  but what does this mean mathematically? is **mat** and **matrix** the same? Or I'm mixing things up here? 1 in the middle is the batch size in my understanding.
- the **decode_ctcBeam** function returns with a list, in the example it gives [2], which should mean 'CH' from the defined classes. How do I generalize this and find the recognized phoneme sequences if I have a larger input matrix and let's say 40 phonemes?

Looking forward to your answers / comments! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

the TF documentation is wrong - beam search with beam width 1 is **NOT** the same as greedy decoding (I created an [issue about this some time ago](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/21051)).

Then, instead of np.reshape you could simply use np.transpose to reorder the dimensions, and then add a dimension for the batch size with size 1 with np.expand_dims.

Finally, regarding the TF beam search implementation: yes, the documentation is not very good.
I used the implementation in a text recognition model, I point you to the lines relevant for you:

- [Create TF beam search operation](https://github.com/githubharald/SimpleHTR/blob/ab6220d63acb31e63e03d77328f45883328fd0ea/src/model.py#L131): take care that merge_repeated=False, as the default setting of TF (which is True) does not make sense for 99.99999% of all relevant use cases. Just follow the variable names of the passed arguments to see how they look like, e.g. the input matrix is ctcIn3dTBC which is a transposed version of the RNN output
- [Transform output of beam search to a char string](https://github.com/githubharald/SimpleHTR/blob/ab6220d63acb31e63e03d77328f45883328fd0ea/src/model.py#L203): the operation returns a list of sparse tensors, which have to be decoded to the char string

Comment: Hey Harry! Thank you for reaching out! I was unaware that beam search with beam width 1 is not the same as greedy decoding. Thank you for sorting that out. I've checked your code about the issue and your text recognition implementation and made a beam search with my own data. However I still have the same issue as in my other comment. The output list of the beam search is much longer and it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: can you provide the input data (the saved numpy array .npy) and the classes which come from the Classes module? Such that I can run the script?

Comment: sent you an e-mail! Thank you in advance!

Comment: As of 7/14/21, both links are inactive

Answer (score 1):

So, I've made some progress since I asked the question, but still haven't figured out how to use the Tensorflow has a CTC Beam Search properly. It seams that setting the top_paths = 1 and beam_width = 1 does give back the greedy search expected output in a list of ints, that can be easily transformed into required phonemes stored in **classes**. The output in this case is:

> -------Greedy---------
>
> Output int list
>
> [1, 22, 39, 14, 32, 8]
>
> ['AE', 'N', ' ', 'G', 'UH', 'D']

In the case of Beam Search the results are bad

> -------Beam Search----------
>
> Output int list
>
> [26, 19, 9, 28, 5, 0, 2, 31, 1, 22, 39, 14, 32, 20, 8, 16, 39, 30, 37, 8]
>
> ['P', 'K', 'DH', 'S', 'AY', 'AA', 'AH', 'TH', 'AE', 'N', ' ', 'G', 'UH', 'L', 'D', 'IH', ' ', 'T', 'Z', 'D']

The reference is 'I'm good'. The list of [1, 22, 39, 14, 32, 8] is inside the Beam search result, the other parts should be the alternative roots? It's pretty suspicious to me.
Anyone have any ideas?

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import Classes

def decode_ctcBeam(matrix, classes):  
    matrix = np.reshape(matrix, (matrix.shape[0], 1,matrix.shape[1]))
    aa_ctc_blank_aa_logits = tf.constant(matrix)
    sequence_length = tf.constant(np.array([len(matrix)], dtype=np.int32))
    
    (decoded_list,), log_probabilities = tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder(inputs=aa_ctc_blank_aa_logits,
                                              sequence_length=sequence_length,
                                              merge_repeated=True,
                                              top_paths=1,
                                              beam_width=4)

    out = list(tf.Session().run(tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(decoded_list)[0]))
    print("Output int list")
    print(out)
    seq_list = get_seq_from_list(out, classes)
    return seq_list
        
def decode_ctcgreedy(matrix, classes):
    
    matrix = np.reshape(matrix, (matrix.shape[0], 1,matrix.shape[1]))
    
    aa_ctc_blank_aa_logits = tf.constant(matrix)
    sequence_length = tf.constant(np.array([len(matrix)], dtype=np.int32))

    (decoded_list,), log_probabilities = tf.nn.ctc_beam_search_decoder(inputs=aa_ctc_blank_aa_logits,
                                              sequence_length=sequence_length,
                                              merge_repeated=True,
                                              top_paths=1,
                                              beam_width=1)

    out = list(tf.Session().run(tf.sparse_tensor_to_dense(decoded_list)[0]))
    print("Output int list")
    print(out)
    seq_list = get_seq_from_list(out, classes)
    
    return seq_list

def get_seq_from_list(int_list, classes):
    out_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(int_list)):        
        out_list.append(classes[int_list[i]])
        
    return out_list

if __name__ == '__main__':

    mat = np.load('../npy_files/a1003.npy')
    classes = Classes.get_classes()
    
    print("-------Greedy---------")
    actual = decode_ctcgreedy(mat, classes)
    print(actual)    
    
    print("\n-------Beam Search----------")
    actual = decode_ctcBeam(mat, classes)
    print(actual)
```